# Install Azure IoT Edge on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am following this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-windows-iot-edge-simulated-device#before-you-get-started) article to install Azure IoT Edge.
But when runs tools\build.cmd --disable-native-remote-modules command, it gives error.

---

~/iot-edge/build ~/iot-edge
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- CMake Install Prefix is /usr/local
-- Looking for **x86_64**
-- Looking for **x86_64** - found
-- AIG architecture: x86_64
-- AIG architecture: x86_64
-- ctest not found...
-- Building ctest...
Submodule 'deps/ctest' (https://github.com/azure/azure-ctest) registered for path 'deps/ctest'
Cloning into 'deps/ctest'...
remote: Counting objects: 250, done.
remote: Total 250 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 250
Receiving objects: 100% (250/250), 164.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (121/121), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
fatal: reference is not a tree: 037e318716e37eba358424380659dd1cd6d0554e
Unable to checkout '037e318716e37eba358424380659dd1cd6d0554e' in submodule path 'deps/ctest'
CMake Error at gatewayFunctions.cmake:122 (message):
  Error pulling submodules: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dependencies-test.cmake:9 (findAndInstall)
  CMakeLists.txt:207 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

### See also "/root/iot-edge/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Could you tell me, what may be the problem ?

Comment: #Issue - It is solved and may be published in next release. https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/pull/351

Answer (score 0):

Note that Azure IoT Edge has been updated and now is based on Docker containers and fully supports Ubuntu as a host. Check out the new docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-iot-edge-works